# Multiple input checks, repeat if conditions are not met

Tags: go

I've used this code to make some inputs checks. On any failed check, I need to ask again for proper input. I used `labels` and `goto` to achieve this, which they seem to be disliked by programmers as a concept.

How could I achieve the same effect without labels/goto? I considered putting all this code in a function and calling itself from inside, but it repeated only once for some reason - didn't keep asking if kept getting wrong answers.

```golang
// 0 exits
var f float64
var n int
startGame := func() {
reception:
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Print(`Give number (1-9): `)
    _, err := fmt.Scan(&f)

    // check letters or symbols
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Letters or symbols not accepted")
        goto reception
    }

    // exit
    if f == 0 {
        os.Exit(0)
    }

    // check for integers only
    if f < 1 || f > 9 || f-math.Ceil(f) != 0 {
        fmt.Println("Only integer numbers between 1-9 are accepted")
        goto reception
    }

    n = int(f)
    // check for empty cells
    if myArray[n-1] == false {
        fmt.Println("Empty cell", n)
        goto reception
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for {}` (for loop without condition) loops forever until `break`.

1. Put the contents of the function in a `for {}`.
2. Remove the label and replace `goto reception` with `continue`. This will cause the current iteration of the loop to end and execution will continue with another iteration, starting from the top of the block.
3. Use `break` at the end to exit the for loop